# Limit user bound ports to arbitrary ranges

Tags: linux, networking, ports

Is it possible to allow user to bind only certain ports?
For example, I was trying to achieve this:

- user1: can bind only on ports 4001 and 4002
- user2: can bind only on ports 5001 and 5002
- and so on...

I have searched for a solution for a long time using SElinux or apparmor but nothing seems to work as these tools can only set rules to certain executables (correct me if i am wrong).

Comment: Seen this? http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/how-can-i-restrict-ports-for-users-to-bind-to-667153/